# Unable to update system from terminal on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, command-line, updates, proxy

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Recently my institute changed network proxy settings. After that, I am unable to update anything from my terminal. Also, new installations from terminal are not possible. I keep getting proxy verification error. However, I am able to do installations from Synaptic Package Manager. 
I have made necessary changes on my apt conf file and have added my latest proxy settings with ID and password. 
Please help me resolve the issue.
Thanks in advance 
SG

Comment: Try to install genome and then reboot the machine. Please use the following command " sudo apt-get install gnome and  sudo reboot".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following parameter to your .bashrc file. Replace `username`, `password`, `proxyserver` and `port` with appropriate values.

`export http_proxy="http://username:password@proxyserver:port"`

Add similar entries for other proxies: `https_proxy` `ftp_proxy` and `socks_proxy`.
After adding these settings source the .bashrc file by entering the following command on terminal

`source .bashrc`

Now try to update with `sudo apt-get`

Comment: it seems there was some error in the apt.conf file. I re-added the proxy userid and password and saved. then it started working fine.